# how to copy the first line to every lines in text file by notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Is there any way to copy first line to each line in txt file by notepad++

Example :

```
progress6139
Ruqayya  Ali Alwan Alhebsi  Completed
Ahmed Saif Completed
Ruqayya Mohammed Ali Alwan Alhebsi  Completed
```

output:

```
progress6139 Ruqayya  Ali Alwan Alhebsi  Completed
progress6139 Ahmed Saif Completed
progress6139 Ruqayya Mohammed Ali Alwan Alhebsi  Completed
```

I have many files with many lines

I used "combine plugins" so all files have been merged  in one file but I want to know the source file of each line

The result of the merge is as follows :

```
C:\Users\ahmedb\Downloads\progress.6009.csv
Ruqayya  Ali Alwan Alhebsi  Completed
Ahmed Saif Completed
Ruqayya Mohammed Ali Alwan Alhebsi  Completed

C:\Users\ahmedb\Downloads\progress.6100.csv
Ruqayya  Ali Alwan Alhebsi  Not Completed
Ahmed Saif Not Completed
Ruqayya Mohammed Ali Alwan Alhebsi  Completed
```

I need the lines as follows

```
C:\Users\ahmedb\Downloads\progress.6009.csv  Ruqayya  Ali Alwan Alhebsi  Completed
C:\Users\ahmedb\Downloads\progress.6009.csv  Ahmed Saif Completed
C:\Users\ahmedb\Downloads\progress.6009.csv  Ruqayya Mohammed Ali Alwan Alhebsi  Completed

C:\Users\ahmedb\Downloads\progress.6100.csv Ruqayya  Ali Alwan Alhebsi  Not Completed
C:\Users\ahmedb\Downloads\progress.6100.csv Ahmed Saif Not Completed
C:\Users\ahmedb\Downloads\progress.6100.csv Ruqayya Mohammed Ali Alwan Alhebsi  Completed
```

Comment: Is there any  way

Comment: The simplest way is: 1) copy (Ctrl+C) the string you want. 2) In the find and replace window, Find: `^` Replace: paste the sing (Ctrl+V) + a space. 3) Click "Replace all"

Comment: I have many files more then 100 text file

Comment: Then the best way is to write a script in your favorite scripting language.

Comment: You could all open 100 files into notepad++ (as one action), and then apply's Toto's suggestion in the same way, there is a button on the find dialog that says: `Replace All in All Opened Documents`

Comment: @PaulT. please note that the first line is filename

Comment: i used "combine plugins" so  all files have been combined  in one file  but  I want to know the source file of each line  ,

Comment: Is there any solution through NOTEPAD++

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as described in the [help] pages.